# Does mongodump lock the database?

Tags: mongodb

I'm in the middle of setting up a backup strategy for mongo, was just curious to know if mongodump locks the database before performing the database dump?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mongdump does not lock the db. It means other read and write operations will continue normally.

Actually, both mongodump and mongorestore are non-blocking. So if you want to mongodump mongorestore a db then its your responsibility to make sure that it is really a desired snapshot backup/restore. To do this, you must stop all other write operations while taking/restoring backups with mongodump/mongorestore. If you are running a sharded environment then its recommended you stop the balancer also.

Comment: The reality of this however is that whatever is running off your database will become so slow it is unusable

Answer (score 19):

I found this on [mongo's google group](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.mongodb.user/70273):

> Mongodump does a simple query on the live system and does not require
>   a shutdown. Like all queries it requires a read lock while running but
>   doesn't not block any more than normal queries.
>
> If you have a replica set you will probably want to use the --oplog
>   flag to do your backups.

#### See the docs for more information

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/backups/

#### Additionally I found this previously asked question

- [MongoDB: mongodump/restore vs. backup up files directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741111/mongodb-mongodump-restore-vs-backup-up-files-directly)

*Excerpt from above question*

> Locking and copying files is only an option when you don't have heavy
>   write load.
>
> `mongodump` can be run against live server. It will create some
>   additional load, so don't do it on peak hours. Also, it is advised to
>   do it on a secondary node (if you don't use replica sets, you should).
>
> There are some complications when you have a DB so large that no
>   single machine can hold it. See [this document](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Backing+Up+Sharded+Cluster).
>
> Also, if you have replica set, you take down one of secondaries and copy its files directly. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Backups: