# I want to BackUp Of my Database which is installed on my servver?

Tags: mongodb

I have to BackUp my database I read some article and i found this command

sudo mongodump --db newdb --out /var/backups/mongobackups/`date +"%m-%d-%y"`

But My database is continuously using my client is using my database which is installed on my purchase server. 
I want to ask that if i run this command on server my client will not effect?
I mean my software which are depend on my server database will not effect .

Comment: You can find this question already asked 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/14833054/8646838

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does mongodump lock the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825557/does-mongodump-lock-the-database)